# Assign selected picklist value as a default value to my Text field?

Tags: formula, servicecloud, sales-cloud, default-value, text

I want to assign selected picklist value as a default value to my Text field.
I am having a `Select_Option__c` field on Lead and a Enter Detail text field. I also want to add the selected value of picklist to the Text field.
I am using Case function for this purpose ,but it is showing error as :

> ":Field Select_Option__c may not be used in this type of formula"

My formula is as follows :

```
CASE({!Select_Option__c}, 
"Before 1st September 1939", "Before 1st September 1939",
"Gulag", "Gulag",
"Military Service in Allied Armies", "Military Service in Allied Armies",
"Other Incarceration", "Other Incarceration",
"Other Incarceration Under 14", "Other Incarceration Under 14",
"Partisan", "Partisan",
"Polish Army","Polish Army",
"Polish Incarceration 44-56","Polish Incarceration 44-56",
"Taken From Parent","Taken From Parent",
"Ukrainian Insurgent Army","Ukrainian Insurgent Army",
"")
```

Can anyone Help ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a wfr that when the field is blank field = pick list field.

If you use a formula field for the text field you will not be able to edit the field. At that point the field is useless as it would be an exact duplicate of the pick list field

To directly answer your question you would need

TEXT() around your pick list merge

Answer (score 1):

You are getting your error because you can't set a default value for your text field based off of a picklist field. You can only use data which is set before a record is created, such as a record type.

From [Default Field Value Considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_default_field_value_considerations.htm&language=en_US):

> Since the default value is inserted before users enter any values in the new record, you cannot use the fields on the current record to create a default field value. For example, you cannot create a default field value on a contact that uses the first initial and last name because those values are not available when you click New to create a contact record. However, you can use the record type because it is selected before the record edit page displays.

A workflow rule sounds like the way you'll want to go if you want to keep your field editable (text field vs formula field).